# Unit testing #ifdef

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

What is the best way to unit test code that's behaviour changes based on an ifdef?

e.g.

```
+ (NSString*) someMethod:(NSString*)value {
    //Do some stuff ...
#ifdef DEBUG
    //Tell user about error
#else
    //Suppress error
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should only need to test release build because this what the user see.

to actually answer your question: you can split the method to 3 method

```
+ (NSString*) someMethod:(NSString*)value {
#ifdef DEBUG
    return [self someMethod_debug:value];
#else
    return [self someMethod_release:value];
#endif
}

+ (void)someMethod_debug:(NSString *)value {
    //Do some stuff ...
    //Tell user about error
}

+ (void)someMethod_release:(NSString *)value {
    //Do some stuff ...
    //Suppress error
}
```

then you can test `someMethod_debug` and `someMethod_release` individually

Comment: Should someMethod_debug also be wrapped in an ifdef?

Comment: you don't have to. the overhead of few more redundant method is not big. but if you wrapped it in `ifdef` then your unit test code for it must be compiled with `DEBUG` flag